# Symbolicate crash logs

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, crash-reports

Q1) How can I symbolicate the entire crash log file. I do have DYSM & APP files with me. Using ATOS command is tedious. My symbolicatecrash is not working.

Q2) If I forgot to capture the DYSM & APP files while generating a build, can I generate & use them after some time given that there is no modification done on that code after the build was generated. Will this be as good as capturing these file at the time of build generation?

Answer (score 11):

A1) Just put DSYM, APP and crash files in one directory. Then open XCode Organizer->iPhone development->Device Logs, and just drag & drop crash log to a list. That's all, if you have a proper dsym file, crash log should appear with symbols in a list.

A2) If there are no modifications done on code, compiler and machine where build was generated, there's some chance. But I never succeed in my attempts to do this.

Comment: You mean drag & drop in the application list. Not able to do so. I am in XCode Organizer->Development->Device Logs and trying to drag in the application pane.

Comment: That's strange. I had encountered the same problem, when I wasn't being able to drag crash log to the application pane, only when I was trying to drag Mac OSX crash log to Device Logs panel. Crash logs from any iOS devices always appear in the list without any problems. May be, there is something wrong with your crash log. Are you copied crash log directly from a device or you created .crash file by yourself (users sometimes send crash logs by email as plain text in the message)?

Comment: Drag it into "Library - Device Logs". Alternatively you can run symbolication from command line yourself, e.g.: `/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTDeviceKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/symbolicatecrash mycrash.crash`

Comment: Has been moved to /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTDeviceKitBase.framework/Versions/A/Resources/symbolicatecrash in XCode 5.

Comment: where is the APP file?

Answer (score 1):

symbolicatecrash is a perl script that uses spotlight to locate the dSYM files that belong to the app that crashed. If you run symbolicatecrash with the -v (verbose) option you'll see something like: 
Searching in Spotlight for dsym with UUID of ...
Running mdfind "com_apple_... == ..."

So, be sure that spotlight works, and the indexing for spotlight is active for the volume where your stuff is located, with the mdutil command: mdutil -s -a 
If the volume your archived Apps are on is not indexed be sure to switch indexing on. (As root/sudo: mdutil -i on /Volumes/...)

Answer (score 1):

You can also translate symbols manually using atos. Read more on my blog: http://www.dev-smart.com/archives/389

Comment: this link is now a 404.